# Where to submit new feature request for BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

This is not a technical question. But I do want to know where I can submit feature request for [[image]google-bigquery](/questions/tagged/google-bigquery)?

I came across a few issues when importing json data using command-line tool `bq load`, but the error message did not provide valuable info for me to locate the error at all.

e.g.,

```
Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0.
Failure details:
- Expected '"' found '4'
- Expected '"' found '3'
- Expected '"' found '4'
- Expected '"' found '3'
```

It will be very helpful if the error message contains the line number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE: As requested by our developers, we've started an official [Google BigQuery API public issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/) to collect feature requests (and for bug reports as well).**

For the bq command line tool itself, the best way to surface issues and feature requests is to add them to the [bq project issue tracker here](http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/issues/list).